# Selenium webelement clickable or not JAVA

Tags: java, selenium, clickable

So there is not a `isClickable()` function in **selenium**. There is however an `isEnabled()` that works most of the time (in combination with `isDisplayed()`), but not always.

I find myself in such a situation. I have an btn (found by css selector) that is greyed out and not clickable but I dont find any way to verify this. (`isEnabled` always true, and is always displayed)/
The element itself has no attributes nor values that differ from the same btn that ís clickable.

I am out of ideas, I tried the `try/catch` with the `expectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)` but thats always returning true as well.

Does anyone have a solution for me or a different way?
Maybe I can verify the CSS bit (never done it before)? Is that a valid assertion tho?

Thanks

Comment: can you share HTML code when it's `greyed out` and when it's actually available  ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/thomarkey/pen/BaRzbwX
the enabled one is the same except for "value"

Comment: I believe `Currently not available` is visible when it's greyed out  ? I am referring to `data-nap` field

Comment: the enabled one is the same except for "value" and an added amount field
like this
https://codepen.io/thomarkey/pen/LYyZaem

Comment: no thats the issue, it remains the same I asked the developer about it but no response yet

Comment: No, I see one more difference `<input class="form-control qty" name="qty" type="number" value="1" min="1">` is present when button is available, but when its greyed out it's not present. Can you confirm once  ?

Comment: yes that is true. I will seperate them from eachothers using this field. 

But I wondered how to do this with just the btns and click functions

Comment: probably I can help you, this can be solved I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a  difference when button is available which is,

```
<input class="form-control qty" name="qty" type="number" value="1" min="1">
```

you can have the below code block to check when to click  :

**code  :**

```
try {
    if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='qty' and @class='form-control qty' and @type='number']")).size()  > 0 ) {
        System.out.println("This means button is available to click");
        // code to click on button should be written here
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Button must be greyed out, if you are seeing this");
        // do some stuff to make button available
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Check the code again, looks like some issue. ");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grayed elements are normally have `disabled` attribute while enabled elements are `enabled` or just missing `disabled` or something similar. This can be a clear indication in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
Have you check this way
```

**Code:**

```
WebElement element =(WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
.executeScript("return document.querySelector('JS Path')");
    
if(element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed()){
element.click();
}else {
    //statement for not displayed   
}
```